# BroadCastReceiver with action DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW not being called

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have a Receiver which will be invoked when device memory is full or low

it is registered in Manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".services.StorageMonitorService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In my app, there is no alive activity, I have only one service which must be work until there is an available space.

problem is that this receiver not works for samsung galaxy s4 device os version 4.4.2, other devices I have tested worked perfectly, is there any other way to determine low memory event?

Comment: Nope my case is different

Comment: This is now deprecated for Android O above. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW